# How can I check who has added a package to cdnjs?

Tags: aws-amplify, cdn

I'm using **aws-amplify** package in my website using **cdnjs**. But i want to clear my doubts regarding security. I have searched on google but not found how any package is added to cdnjs. I just only want to confirm there is no middle man between aws-amplify and me. Please can someone explain me how packages are added to cdnjs and how to check the information regarding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> clear my doubts regarding security

The [About Us](https://cdnjs.com/about) page for cdnjs states that they are powered by Cloudflare.

You're pretty much using one of the safest CDNs out there.

> how packages are added to cdnjs

You won't find any information on that as they simply just compile/publish the open-source code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js?utm_source=cdnjs&utm_medium=cdnjs_link&utm_campaign=cdnjs_library). There's no other way.

You have no reason for any worry.

Comment: Thanks for answer. is the compile/publish process done by cdnjs it self. or it is done by the user who have created pull request ?

Comment: cdnjs themselves :)